# seleniumをブラウザ上で実行できない

Tags: python, selenium

環境

- Conoha VPS
- CentOS Apache2.0
- Python 3.75
- Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116
- ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39
- selenium Version: 3.141.0

ディレクトリ
/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py      755

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import chromedriver_binary
import cgi # CGIモジュールのインポート
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=options)
print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8") #HTMLを出力するために必要
print("") #HTMLを出力するために必要
driver.get('https://yahoo.co.jp')
print(driver.title)
```

/var/www/cgi-bin上で

```
python test.py
```

を実行すると

```
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Yahoo! JAPAN
```

と結果が返ってきます。

しかし、

```
xxx.xx.xx(IPアドレス)/cgi-bin/test.py
```

をWEB上で開くと500エラーになります。

エラーのログを確認すると

```
no module named selenium python
```

と出てきます。
seleniumはすでに入っているはずで、以下の結果も確認済みです。

```
pip install selenium 


    Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)
```

`pip3 show webdriver`を実行すると

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: webdriver
```

のエラーが出てきます。

また、以前別のサーバー（IPアドレス）で同様の環境で、WEB上で「Yahoo! JAPAN」と出力することに成功しています。
そのサーバーでは
`pip3 show webdriver`を実行するとなにも出力されません。

何か足りないものはあるでしょうか？
たくさんのサイトを見て何時間も挑戦しましたが、私には解決できませんでした。

お力添えいただけると幸いです。
他に必要な情報があればお知らせください。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: タイトルの言葉だけかもしれませんが「ブラウザ上で実行」というが誤解なのでは？ 「ApacheサーバーのCGIとして実行するPythonスクリプトでseleniumがimportできない」というのがより正確な状況の気がします。そうすると対話的に動作確認した時のユーザーとApacheを実行するユーザーが同じなのかどうか、別ならそのユーザー用のPython環境でseleniumがinstallされているかどうかなのでは？ あるいは同じユーザーでもPATH等の各種設定まで同じになっているか等でしょうか。

Comment: 質問に書かれている「xxx.xx.xx(IPアドレス)/cgi-bin/test.pyをWEB上で開く」というのは、webブラウザのアドレス欄に”xxx.xx.xx(IPアドレス)/cgi-bin/test.py”と入力して、リターンキーを押すという事ですか？
「エラーのログを確認すると」のログは、どちらのログですか（ブラウザ側か、サーバ側か）？

Comment: こちら [WEB上（CGI）でseleniumを実行できない](https://teratail.com/questions/278712) で動かしているPython版数が違うのでは？ という回答が付いてます。結果はまだのようですが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
コマンド上では結果が取得できますが、「ApacheサーバーのCGIとして実行するPythonスクリプトでseleniumがimportできない」が正しい言い方かもしれません。


＞「xxx.xx.xx(IPアドレス)/cgi-bin/test.pyをWEB上で開く」というのは、webブラウザのアドレス欄に”xxx.xx.xx(IPアドレス)/cgi-bin/test.py”と入力して、リターンキーを押すという事ですか？

はい、その通りです。

エラーログは/etc/httpd/logs/error_log　の結果になります。

#!/usr/bin/env python　を
#!/usr/bin/env python3　にしてみると下記のエラーが出てきました。
AH01215: /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory

Comment: 上記紹介した teratail のサイトで状況が進展して別の回答で解決していました。Apacheで呼び出している環境とモジュールをインストールした環境が別だったようです。